# Axios Request shows 'Pending' in Network Tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a react app that fetches data from an `https://api.data.io/api/v1`, but I was getting some cors errors while making the request, so I decided to create a proxy server.

But now, when I make a request from the frontend, no data is returned, and when I check the network tab, I see `pending`. What am I missing and what's the better way to do this?

`server.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(cors());
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.data.io/api/v1",
  headers: {
    "x-id-apix":
      "xxxxxx",
  },
});

const getAllNodes = () => {
  console.log("yay!");
  return instance.get("/nodes", {});
};

app.get("/nodes", getAllNodes);
```

`frontend: index.js`

```
const newinstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

// Get all nodes
export const getNodes = () => {
  return newinstance.get('/nodes', {});
};
```

Comment: You may want to check out both an Express and general JS async tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this isn't at all how you use `express` on the server.  You are encouraged to consult [documentation and examples](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).  *Returning* does nothing.  You would send a response by using the "response" object passed to the route handler function.  For example:

```
const getAllNodes = (req, res) => {
  console.log("yay!");
  instance.get("/nodes", {}).then(data => res.json(data));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you don't return anything from your api I believe. Can you try something like this ?

```js
const getAllNodes = async (req, res) => {
    const {data} = await instance.get("/nodes" {
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    data.pipe(res);
})
```

To pipe the request from axios to express response